# Store time in DB and resume after log in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

We already know that the following code in PHP will log the user out after 5 mins of inactivity.

```
$timeout = 5*60; // Set timeout minutes
$logout_redirect_url = "index.php"; // Set logout URL

if (isset($_SESSION['start_time'])) {
    $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
    if ($elapsed_time >= $timeout) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $logout_redirect_url");
    }
}
$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
```

I want to implement a modification of the current code and do something like this:

- Assume the user logs out when he had 3 minutes left before automatic logout(assuming the time doesn't restart for him after his inactivity for 2 minutes), we keep track of the time he has left by storing it in a DB (MySQL) and later on start reducing from the same 3 minutes after he logs back in. How can i do this?

Comment: You're asking how to do something that you just explained yourself. Your own explanation says to store the time in the database, then retrieve it and use it. So...do that.

Comment: @m59 the issue is, how can i compare that time with the current time and continue using this code? If i retrieve that time() it simply won't be comparable with the current time()

Comment: I don't get what you mean. All you need to do is use the time from the database rather than the `time()` function.

Comment: @m59 i mean that: How will i convert then 3 minutes by THEN with the 3 minutes by NOW? The code above is simple comparing the current time with the time 5 minutes ago while the time i store in DB will be (say) 2 days old. How on earth can i compare that time with new time() (i.e. Time after 2 days). Got me now?

Comment: Ahh. give me a few minutes. There's a few ways to handle that.

Comment: Great... its like a stop watch. You start a timer, you pause (store in DB) and then resume some time later. I only need to save minutes and seconds.

Comment: All done. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track by the time used, not the currentTime/storedTime. Just use those to figure out the time remaining. This is a quick example. There may be some small errors and improvements that can be made. It should be plenty to help you implement a solution.

User visits page:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['start_time'])) {
  $_SESSION['start-time'] = time();
}

$timeLeft = //get time from db

//if there is a value in the db, that is the time left, otherwise, use the max time allowed (new timer)
$timeLeft = (!empty($timeLeft)) ? $timeLeft : $timeAllowed
$timePassed = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
if ($timePassed > $timeAllowed) {
  //logout
}
```

Then, when the user leaves:

```
$timeLeft = $timeAllowed - (time() - $_SESSION['start_time']);
//Store $timeLeft in the database - should be a value like 180 (3 minutes)
```